# Addition of inert gas to equilibrium mixture under constant pressure

Tags: equilibrium, gas-laws, pressure

Adding inert gas under constant volume will not disturb equilibrium. But I want to know what would happen if inert gases are added at constant pressure.
If total pressure remains constant and inert gases are added, then mole fraction of any gas participating in equilibrium decreases and hence partial pressure decreases. 
If $\Delta n$ is non zero, then $K$ changes. But how can $K$ change if temperature remains constant?

Comment: Try to reason backwards: you know K does not change when the temperature remains constant, what should happen to the equilibrium position and the partial pressure to make it so? Does the system still remain at equilibrium?

Comment: I was using the android app. It did not suggest any results bases on the title. I will delete the thread.

Comment: How do I delete it?

Comment: Under your post there should be a delete button. I'm accessing the question via a computer but there should be something similar on Android.